# Is it violation of of copyright to Share freeware APK?

Tags: copyright

I think Stackoverflow is not the right place to ask this. And I love stackexchange network so Had a quick look @ the network and decided to ask it there. Is it okay to host and share freeware Android apk application on my site? Every app's details page also contains direct link to play store so that they can also download it from Play. We won't host any pirated apps and also won't modify any app. And there are also a link for removal request. If the developer can claim his authority and ask us to remove his app then we will immediately remove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that is a violation. You need permission first, not an opt out system. Among other things you are causing significant additional support costs for the developers.

And what value are you adding by hosting the APK rather than just linking to the play store?

Comment: Quote= And what value are you adding by hosting the APK rather than just linking to the play store? I already added a link to allow visitors to download from play store.. People love apk. Android is worldwide now. There are a number of people who like to wownload apk than from play store. And how "additional support costs for the developers."?

Comment: here is a screenshot how the download link setted up http://oi59.tinypic.com/1zbs8l4.jpg

Comment: For a freeware app, it's mission is to be installed in android device. The more install and the more using on Android is better (I think so). I think downloading from playstore only doesn't matter. At lease for freeware app.

Comment: Play store manages updates and ensures that people have the latest version, yours does not. By breaching copyright you will be liable for any additional cost you cause them to occur, even when the software itself is free. At any rate this is the developers decision to make, not yours.

Comment: Ok it is a violation. But how deep? like a cup, bowl, pool or ocean?

Comment: There is no limit. Just don't do it.